# verifying one td tag condition and how to select another td tag in same row of a table

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

et

```
the_input_elements = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")

For Each input_element In the_input_elements


    If input_element.getAttribute("colid") = "8" Then
        If input_element.innerText = "CUSTOMER" Then

          input_element.Focus
end if
exit for
next
```

Comment: A td tag is not an input element. Where is the html snippet? What are you trying to do? What is actually your question?

Comment: Please share the relevant html and explain what you are trying to do and explain what isn't working. You are currently testing the same td node with both conditions and assuming all td nodes have the colid attribute.